# System::IO::Ports not appearing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

As a beginner on c++ with previous experience with C# I wanted to recreate a serial communication program I did before which communicates with a Arduino. But before I can even begin, i'm having problems using the namespace "System::IO::Ports", the only thing that pops up on visual studio 2013 is "System::IO::IsolatedStorage". Any solutions to this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and call the Windows API functions for serial ports.  Figuring out the legacy API is easier than working around [all the brokenness in the .NET wrapper](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport).

Comment: According to [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cant-use-system-io-ports.141316/) and [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/system-io-ports-problem-its-not-there.76808/), make sure you are using .NET 2.0, not subset.

Comment: @Imirak this seems like the right thing to do, but how do I change this (in visual studio 2013)?

Comment: File -> build settings -> player settings -> other settings -> API compatibility level -> .NET 2

Comment: @Imirak I believe that is for Unity, not visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Be sure to use one of the provided project templates in the CLR node to get started.  They are meant to help you avoid simple mistakes like forgetting to reference System.dll

Comment: Hans Passant thank you that worked!